# Microsoft Teams dark mode color issue in android

Tags: microsoft-teams

In the Teams add-in app developed webview,
if you apply dark mode and click select tag, you can't see the text well
I try change text color using CSS but It dosen't work
How can I change it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU9iN.png)

Comment: Could you please share repro steps to try at our end?

Comment: 1. Create a select tag on your web page
2. Create an app in the Teams App studio
3. Set up your web page in App Manifest as follows.

  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "teams.tab.select",
      "name": "select",
      "contentUrl": "https://yourwebpage",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    },

4. Click the select tag in dark mode

Comment: We are able to repro your issue. We have raised a bug for it. We will inform you once we have any updates on this bug.

Comment: The bug has fixed now. Could you please check and confirm?

Comment: I Confirmed that the bug has been fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We had raised a bug for this, and the bug has fixed now.